# pass output as an argument for cp in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls, cp

I'm taking a unix/linux class and we have yet to learn variables or functions. We just learned some basic utilities like the flag and pipeline, output and append to file. On the lab assignment he wants us to find the largest files and copy them to a directory.

I can get the 5 largest files but I don't know how to pass them into cp in one command

```
ls -SF | grep -v / | head -5 | cp ? Directory
```

Comment: `man xargs` is your friend...

Comment: See also [How to pass `find` results to `cp` such that file names with spaces work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724826/how-to-pass-find-results-to-cp-such-that-file-names-with-spaces-work).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It would be:

```
cp `ls -SF | grep -v / | head -5` Directory
```

assuming that the pipeline is correct. The backticks substitute in the line the output of the commands inside it.

You can also make your tests:

```
cp `echo a b c` Directory
```

will copy all `a`, `b`, and `c` into `Directory`.

Comment: While this may work, be aware [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: You're right. It is however difficult to list the files in order by size, and `ls -SF` is easy enough. In fact, this solution is not correct if the files have spaces in them.

Answer (score 61):

I would do:

```
cp $(ls -SF | grep -v / | head -5) Directory
```

xargs would probably be the best answer though.

```
ls -SF | grep -v / | head -5 | xargs -I{} cp "{}" Directory
```

Comment: Highly useful. Would be nice to explain the various options and their logic.

Answer (score 9):

Use backticks `like this` or the dollar sign $(like this) to perform command substitution. Basically this pastes each line of standard ouput of the backticked command into the surrounding command and runs it. Find out more in the bash manpage under "Command Substitution."

Also, if you want to read one line at a time you can read individual lines out of a pipe stream using "while read" syntax:

```
ls | while read varname; do echo $varname; done
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to pipe a list of window ids (grepped and cut from the output of `xwininfo`) into the `xdotool` so I could close a bunch of error dialogs that popped up. This syntax works with zsh :)

Answer (score 2):

If your `cp` has a "-t" flag (check the man page), that simplifies matters a bit:

```
ls -SF | grep -v / | head -5 | xargs cp -t DIRECTORY
```

The find command gives you more fine-grained ability to get what you want, instead of `ls | grep` that you have. I'd code your question like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%s\n" | 
sort -t $'\t' -k2 -nr | 
head -n 5 | 
cut -f 1 | 
xargs echo cp -t DIRECTORY
```

Comment: I checked the man page on my system (macOS 10.12.1), and the -t option doesn't appear to exist: 
`~$ cp -t main.c main2.c
cp: illegal option -- t`

Comment: I think the -t is a GNU option and Mac is not GNU.