# How To Pass Find results to CP such that File Names with Spaces work

Tags: bash

I'm trying to copy files with specific attachments to a different directory with their relative paths preserved. From the original top path I am calling:

```
cp --parents `find . -name \*.pdf -print` /new_path/
```

I believe this works; however only if the file found has no spaces in the name.

I also tried:

```
cp --parents `find . -name \*.pdf -print0` /new_path/
```

This doesn't work obviously because without the new line character cp receives the wrong name.

Is it possible to surround the find result with quotes ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -name \*.pdf -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -Ifoo cp --parents foo /new_path/
```

Or

```
find . -name \*.pdf -exec cp --parents {} /new_path/ \;
```

Comment: find . -name \*.pdf -exec cp --parents {} /new_path/ \;  Seems to have done it

Answer (score 3):

Another way. This would copy all files in one call as multiple arguments to `cp`.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec cp --parents -t /new_path '{}' '+'
```