# Copy the files and folders which got changed between 2 SVN revision

Tags: linux, svn

In my project I frequently need to copy the files/folders which got changed between 2 SVN revisions.

I am able to get the list of these changed files/folders using below command:

```
svn diff -r START REVISION:END REVISION --summarize
```

Now I would like to copy the list returned by the above command to a specific server location for further operations on it.

Currently I am executing the copy command like this:

```
cp --parents file1.php, file2.php, upload/upload.php
```

My question is: **Is there any single Linux command which will perform above 2 mentioned operations?** (Directly copy the files which were returned by the SVN diff command.)

I have tried the Pipes operator for performing chain commands.

```
svn diff -r START REVISION:END REVISION --summarize | cp --parents
```

But it doesn't work.

I am sure that there is a way to combine both the operation using one single command, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass output as an argument for cp in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833582/pass-output-as-an-argument-for-cp-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks tripleee. I got the solution from your suggested Link.

The final command is 

cp --parents `svn diff -r 24:35 --summarize` ../testcp/

Answer (score 0):

The following is the answer of my question. As I have used substitute operator which make sure that the output of the svn diff command pasted as a input for the CP command.

```
cp --parents `svn diff -r 24:35 --summarize` ../testcp/
```