# Git Bash Windows:piping output of ls -t|head -n 3 to cp

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'd like to copy my 3 most recently downloaded files to another directory using Git Bash. I can list them using

`ls -t ~/Downloads|head -n 3`

, but how do I pass them as input to the cp function so that I can
copy them to some other directory?

I'm pretty new to programming and Bash, so my apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: This is not related to git, just a bash question actually. What you're looking for is xargs.

Answer (score 1):

Note: you don't need git bash to copy those files: if you have added `<git>/usr/bin` to your `%PATH%` (as [I do here, with this simplified
`PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172186/6309)), you can do that Linux command sequence in any regular `CMD` session:

```
vonc@VONC D:\git\git
> where xargs
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\xargs.exe

vonc@VONC D:\git\git
> ls -t|head -3|xargs | xargs -I\{\} echo  "{}" a
wt-status.h wt-status.c worktree.h a
```

See also "[pass output as an argument for `cp` in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833683/6309)", which mentions xargs.
The other option (`cp $(ls -t | head -3) Directory`) would have to be in a bash only.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!